# Closed formula for the difference of central binomial coefficients in terms of earlier central binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to find a way to rewrite
$$  
4\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n+2}{n+1}
$$
in the form
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m a_k \binom{2(n-k)}{n-k},
$$
where $m$ is a fixed integer, and the coefficients $a_k$ are all integers. That is, rewrite it in terms of a finite integer combination of earlier central binomial coefficients. I tried
$$  
\binom{2n+2}{n+1} = \frac{4n+2}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n},
$$
but it turns out that $\frac{4n+2}{n+1}$ is not an integer, so I get a non-integer multiple of $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$. Does anyone know a similar formula involving only integers?
What I am looking for is a formula like
$$
D_n = a D_{n-k}, 
$$
where $D_n$ is the central binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$, and $a$ is an integer. We may allow several terms of the form $a_i D_i$ on the right-hand side, but I would prefer to have only a fixed number of them.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "closed formula?" Your original expression $4\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$ looks like a closed formula to me. It is also a simple formula only involving integers.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I didn't notice that. +1

Comment: @OP: What you have _is_ already a closed formula. If you wish to simplify it, you can simply use the definition $\binom nr:=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ and simplify it with algebraic manipulations. Did you perhaps want a simplification via a combinatorial argument or something?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It is true that we need some clarification here. What I want is a closed formula that involves lesser terms, such as $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$, with integer coefficients only.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you want by editing the original question (people should not have to dig through the comments to figure out what you mean). I am still unclear what you mean by "lesser terms." Would replacing $\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$ with $\binom{2n+1}{n}+\binom{2n+1}{n+1}=2\binom{2n+1}{n}$, resulting in an expression of $$4\binom{2n}{n}-2\binom{2n+1}{n},$$qualify as "lesser terms?"

Comment: There are an unlimited number of "closed form" answers but until you clarify exactly why you need this, we can't give a good answer.

Comment: You will probably get better results if you tell us *why* you want a different form for that expression, so we can come up with something that fits that need. Barring that, you will need to give **objectively verifiable** properties that you want your form to have, otherwise this question is too broad and will be closed.

Comment: OK, I have already edited the question a little bit, but perhaps it is still not enough. I will try to clarify it further in response to your questions and comments. Responding to your question, Mike, the term $\binom{2n+1}{n}$ would not qualify as a lesser term, because it is not a central binomial coefficient.

Comment: I have already edited the question in order to address some of your comments and answer your questions. I hope that it is clearer now. In any case, all the formulas that you have provided are quite interesting. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your understanding and your feedback.

Comment: It is very clear now, thank you! I think know how to rewrite your extension with a summation of $n$ earlier central binomial coefficients, but I can’t yet do a fixed number.

Answer (score 3):

We can use typically known identities of binomial coefficients for the simplification

$$4\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n+2}{n+1}=4\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n+1}{n+1}-\binom{2n+1}{n}$$
$$=4\binom{2n}{n} - \frac{2n+1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$$
$$=4\binom{2n}{n} - \frac{4n+2}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=2C_n$$

Where $(C_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is the Catalan sequence which is a mapping $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: This is fine, but again we have the problem that the factor $\frac{2}{n+1}$ is not an integer.

Comment: I've added some things and link, which will address your question

Comment: (+1) I was just about to post something very similar before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

- $$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} =  
  \binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
- $$\binom{n}{k}  =  
  \binom{n}{n-k}$$

So we have
\begin{align}
...&=  
4\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n+1}{n+1} - \binom{2n+1}{n}\\
&=  
4\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n+1} - \binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n}- \binom{2n}{n-1}
\\&=  
2\binom{2n}{n} - 2\binom{2n}{n-1}
\\&= {2\over n+1}
\binom{2n}{n} \end{align}

Comment: This is fine, but again we have the problem that the factor $\frac{2}{n+1}$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote it once you showed that
$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1} = \frac{4n+2}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}\implies \binom{2n}{n}=\frac{n+1}{4n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1} $$ Then
$$4\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\frac{4n+4}{4n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}- \binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2 n+1}\binom{2 n+2}{n+1}$$

Comment: That's very nice, thanks a lot, but again, we have the coefficient $\frac{1}{2n+1}$, which is not an integer.